# Python Multithreading: Check active domains with multithreading in python optimally

Tags: python, multithreading, file, python-requests, optimal

The idea of the program is to check for domains/subdomains living (via http/https protocol) in the [subdomains.txt](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/abuvanth/b9fcbaf7c77c2954f96c6e556138ffe8/raw/ff86e959dede67595676f99bb71f1e85215e937b/google-subdomain-list.txt) file.

I did this by using `HEAD requests` to domains/subdomains and receiving the response status code. If the status code is available, the domain or subdomain is live. (`load_url_http` function)

To speed up the program, I used concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor with a number of threads of 200 However, even after increasing the number of threads to 300, the program's speed isn't much improved.

I want an improvement in my program to be able to send thousands of requests at once. Below is part of my source code:

**python-request-multil.py**

```py
import time

import requests
import concurrent.futures


def load_url_http(protocol: str, domain: str, timeout: int = 10):
        try:
            conn = requests.head(protocol + "://" + domain, timeout=timeout)
            return conn.status_code
        except Exception:
            return None


#--- main ---#
start_time = time.time()

worker = 400
protocol = "http"
timeout = 10

print("Number of worker:", worker)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=worker) as executor:
    # The file object that the subdomain lives on will be written to
    file_live_subdomain = open("live_subdomains.txt", "a")
    
    # load domain/subdomain list from file
    URLS = open("subdomains.txt", "r").read().split("\n")
    URLS_length = len(URLS)
    
    # Count the number of live subdomains
    live_count = 0
    
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {
        executor.submit(load_url_http, protocol, url, timeout): url for url in URLS
    }
    
    for i, future in zip(range(URLS_length), concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url)):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        print(f"\r-->  Checking live subdomain.........{i+1}/{URLS_length}", end="")
        try:
            data = future.result()
            
            # If `load_url_http` returns any status code
            if data != None:
                # print(f'{protocol}://{url}:{data}')
                live_count = live_count + 1
                file_live_subdomain.write(f"\n{protocol}://" + url)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)
    print(f"\n[+] Live domain: {live_count}/{URLS_length}", end="")
    file_live_subdomain.close()

print("\n--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Run:

```
┌──(quangtb㉿QuangTB)-[/mnt/e/DATA/Downloads]
└─$ python3 python-request-multil.py
Number of worker: 100
-->  Checking live subdomain.........1117/1117
[+] Live domain: 344/1117
--- 67.41670227050781 seconds ---

┌──(quangtb㉿QuangTB)-[/mnt/e/DATA/Downloads]
└─$ python3 python-request-multil.py
Number of worker: 200
-->  Checking live subdomain.........1117/1117
[+] Live domain: 344/1117
--- 54.6825795173645 seconds ---

┌──(quangtb㉿QuangTB)-[/mnt/e/DATA/Downloads]
└─$ python3 python-request-multil.py
Number of worker: 300
-->  Checking live subdomain.........1117/1117
[+] Live domain: 339/1117
--- 54.186068058013916 seconds ---

┌──(quangtb㉿QuangTB)-[/mnt/e/DATA/Downloads]
└─$ python3 python-request-multil.py
Number of worker: 400
-->  Checking live subdomain.........1117/1117
[+] Live domain: 344/1117
--- 54.19181728363037 seconds ---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python `multithreading` doesn't actually run in parallel, all the threads run under 1 process and that process runs only on 1 core (of the cpu).

You can create as many `threads` as you want and is won't solve the problem and can actually make it worse, because those 300 `threads` are running on 1 `cpu core` but that 1 `cpu core` can only run 1 `command` at a time, so what ends up happening is that the `cpu core` needs to run a few `commands` on 1 `thread` and then `switch` to another `thread` and run a few `commands` on that other `thread` and then `switch` to another one and etc... the `switching` action between `threads` takes resources and in that time your program code doesn't run. So in the end if you open to many `threads` your `cpu core` will spend more time on `switching` between `threads` than on executing your program.

What you can do to actually run your code simultaneously is to open a few `processes` instead of `threads` using the `multiprocessing` library, and then your code will run on a number of `cores`, and the same thing here, don't open hundreds of `processes`, open only a few, I recommend on openings 1 `process` for each `core` your `cpu` has, the `multiprocessing` library has a built-in function the returns the number of `cores` your `cpu` has:

```
import multiprocessing
print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

note that because of the fact that the `processes` actually run your code simultaneously your `prints` can interfere with each other so you will need to use `multiprocessing.Lock()` and do something like this:

```
import multiprocessing

lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

lock.acquire()
print("something")
lock.release()
```

do `lock.acquire()` before each `print` and `lock.release()` after (if you won't release the lock your program will be stuck) and this will make sure that your `prints` won't get in each other.

---

EDIT:

in your case because of the `timeout` it will actually be better to open a few `processes` and in each `process` something like 20 `threads`.

because if the `process` is waiting 10 seconds for each failed address it will end up being slower than opening a lot of `threads`

so for your case the `fastest` way I can think of is opening a few `processes` and in each `process` open 20 to 30 `threads`

You can try something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import random
import threading
import time
import requests


MAX_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
MAX_NUMBER_OF_THREADS_IN_EACH_PROCESS = 30
PROTOCOL = "http"
TIMEOUT = 4
START_TIME = time.time()


def load_url_http(protocol: str, domains: list[str], timeout: int = 10):
    with open("live_subdomains.txt", "a") as live_domains_file:
        for domain in domains:
            try:
                conn = requests.head(protocol + "://" + domain, timeout=timeout)
                if conn.status_code is not None:
                    live_domains_file.write(f"{protocol}://{domain}\n")
            except Exception:
                pass
    return


def create_threads_for_process(protocol: str, domains: list[str], timeout: int = 10):
    # create threads
    threads_list = []
    threads_urls = {}
    start = 0
    number_of_threads_to_open = len(domains) if len(domains) < MAX_NUMBER_OF_THREADS_IN_EACH_PROCESS \
        else MAX_NUMBER_OF_THREADS_IN_EACH_PROCESS
    for i in range(1, number_of_threads_to_open + 1):
        # distribute the work of this process evenly between all the threads
        if i != number_of_threads_to_open:
            threads_urls[i] = domains[start:(len(domains) // number_of_threads_to_open) * i]
            start = (len(domains) // number_of_threads_to_open) * i
        else:
            threads_urls[i] = domains[start:]
        # create and start the thread
        thread = threading.Thread(target=load_url_http,
                                  args=(protocol, threads_urls[i], timeout,),
                                  daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        threads_list.append(thread)
    # wait for all threads to finish
    while threads_list:
        for thread in threads_list:
            if not thread.is_alive():
                threads_list.remove(thread)
        time.sleep(0.8)


def main():
    with open("live_subdomains.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write("")
    with open("subdomains.txt", "r") as file:
        urls = file.read().split("\n")
    random.shuffle(urls)  # shuffle the urls list
    # create the processes
    processes_list = []
    processes_urls = {}
    start = 0
    number_of_processes_to_open = len(urls) if len(urls) < MAX_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES else MAX_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES
    for i in range(1, number_of_processes_to_open + 1):
        if i != number_of_processes_to_open:
            # give each process an even amount of work
            processes_urls[i] = urls[start:(len(urls) // number_of_processes_to_open) * i]
            start = (len(urls) // number_of_processes_to_open) * i
        else:
            # the last process will get a bit more / a bit less in
            # case len(urls) isn't dividable by number_of_processes_to_open
            processes_urls[i] = urls[start:]
        # create the process, start it and add to processes list
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=create_threads_for_process,
                                          args=(PROTOCOL, processes_urls[i], TIMEOUT,),
                                          daemon=True)
        process.start()
        processes_list.append(process)
    # wait for all processes to finish
    while multiprocessing.active_children():
        time.sleep(0.8)
    # print result
    with open("live_subdomains.txt", "r") as live_urls_file:
        live_count = len(live_urls_file.read().split("\n")) - 1  # -1 empty line at the end
    print(f"\n[+] Live domain: {live_count}/{len(urls)}", end="")
    print("\n--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - START_TIME))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

in this code I opened 1 `process` for each `core` the `cpu` has, and in each `process` I opened 30 `threads`, also you don't need to wait 10 seconds for a `replay` something like 5 seconds is enough especially when you use `HEAD` and not `GET`.

I run your code and compared to mine, your code took **35 seconds** to finish, mine took **25 seconds** and that is on 1117 urls, **the bigger the url list the more significant it will be.**